# Confusion about unbiasedness of LS estimator in LM

Tags: least-squares, linear-model

Let's consider a classical linear model $Y = X \theta + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ being the error vector and let's suppose furthermore that :

1. $\Bbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$
2. $Var(\epsilon_i) = \sigma_i^2$
3. $Cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j) \neq 0$ if $i \neq j$

Then is it true that the LS estimator for $\theta$ is unbiased ?

I thought that a necessary and sufficient condition for guaranteeing unbiasedness of the estimator would be to have homoscedastic uncorrelated errors, which is a stronger assumption than the ones I have made above, but I am not quite sure anymore.

Could you please enlighten me ?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbiasedness is a property of expectations, not of variances around those expectations.

$$\mathbb{E}\hat{\beta} = \mathbb{E}[(X'X)^{-1}X'Y] = \mathbb{E}[(X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta + \epsilon)] = \beta + \mathbb{E}[(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon]$$

All we need for unbiasedness - $\mathbb{E}\hat{\beta} = \beta$ -is that the last term on the far right equals zero.

If $X$ is nonstochastic (not one of the assumptions listed above), then:

$$\mathbb{E}[(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon] = (X'X)^{-1}X'\mathbb{E}\epsilon = 0$$

which is true by your first assumption.

If $X$ is stochastic, life becomes more difficult, and we usually rely on assumptions that lead to good asymptotic properties, e.g., consistency.
For example, with an autoregressive regression, we get biased but consistent estimates under some fairly mild assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and you are right, I should have mentioned whether X is considered as a deterministic vector or not. This is much clearer now.